# Deciding where f is differentiable and where it is not.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Am I right to say that the function will not be differentiable at x=1 and x=-1, but differentiable everywhere else?

How can I prove those claims?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about at $x=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is even, you only need to consider $[0,\infty[$, and the $-1$ at the end can be thrown away. To show that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, try calculating the left and right limits of the difference quotient.